# Android Studio, не показывает Menu

Tags: java, android, actionbar, menu

Добрый день. Создаю новый проект в Android Studio используя шаблон Blank Activity. В режиме Design в activity_main.xml не на одной из версий телефона Menu не отображается, хотя в эмуляцие оно есть и на реальном телефоне тоже есть. Как сделать что бы в режиме Design оно тоже отображалось.
Пример: 
[image: В режиме Design]

[image: При эмуляции]

Comment: там, где написано `AppTheme`, выберете другую тему, какая вас устроит

Comment: Уже пробовал, не помогает, в режме Design ничего не отоброжается

Comment: А зачем отображать? Поверьте, этот дизайнер еще много вас будет подводить и ругаться на ваш даже правельный код. Привыкайте, часто придеться форму собирать через исходный код, в то время как дизайнер будет показывать одни предупреждения и ошибки.

Comment: Сам как-то искал ответ на этот вопрос, нашел здесь: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685825/android-studio-preview-pane-not-rendering-actionbar